# How to append to the first line of a file?

Tags: sed

How can you use sed to replace the entire first line of a file with that first line plus some additional text?  For example, how can I append `-foo` to a file that contains only one line.

`testfile` contents start:

```
some-text
```

`testfile` contents end:

```
some-text-foo
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **How to append to the first line of a file?**
>
> How can you use sed to replace the entire first line of a file with
>   that first line plus some additional text?

Here's another way to append a string to the end of line number 1 with SED on Windows then convert it back to DOS format for EOL characters i.e. CRLF rather than LF...

### First Command (append characters `-foo` to end of first line only)

```
SED -i "1 s|$|-foo|" "C:\Path\testfile.txt"
```

### Second Command (convert EOL back to carriage return line feed)

```
SED -i "s/$/\r/" "C:\Path\testfile.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '1{s/$/-foo/}' file
```

1 for first line, you can use `num,num` to assign range, eg 3,5 is change line 3 to line 5. s for substitute, $ means the end of the line.  If you want change the file right away, use `-i`  parameter, anyway, use it with caution.

```
awk 'FNR==1{print $0 "-foo";}' file(s)
```

awk is more powerful, but don't have -i parameter to change file right away.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with

```
sed -i '1!b;s/$/\-foo/g' testfile
```

This takes the file, looks at the first line only (1!b;) looks for the end of line ($) and replaces it with the string you want.